# Как лучше хранить объём данных в базе данных

Tags: mysql

Объём данных может быть в мегабайтах, гигабайтах, терабайтах. Какой лучше выбрать тип данных?

Answer (score 2):

Лучше хранить в байтах. Для **MySql** максимальное число 18446744073709551615 может храниться в `BIGINT UNSIGNED`. Если этого не достаточно, то можно хранить размер в виде строки.

Comment: Тогда тип `BIGINT` (мне кажется, ТС как раз интересует что конкретно писать -- INT, DOUBLE или что-то еще...)

Comment: @avp спасибо. добавил в ответ.